# Spring framework fails to detect bean in kotlin file due to generated @Metadata annotation

Tags: java, spring, kotlin

After a week of searching for answer to why my Spring project fails to start, I found the issue myself, I was using Kotlin to create JPA Entity classes, which is supposed to be allowed (I've seen multiple examples on the internet), but fails in my case.

To show an example, I created two files, both describe same Entity bean with autogenerated Id and a String, one file is plain Java and one is Kotlin

Java version:

```java
@Entity
public class Example {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long Id;
    String name;

    public Example() {} //for jpa

    public Example(Long Id, String name) {
        this.Id = Id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

And it works correctly, the application starts without problems.

Now here's a Kotlin version:

```kotlin
@Entity
open class Example(@Id @GeneratedValue var Id : Long,
                  var name : String){
}
```

Trying to run the application now fails with a generic java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError, which comes from other class that is trying to utilise the Example class
(Of course I'm not keeping both versions at once). Also I understand right now it would not work on its own because no-arg constructor is needed, but it doesn't even detect the class yet!

I analysed what Kotlin compiler produces, and noticed the autogenerated @Metadata annotation is the culprit. I even tried adding an empty one to my java version of class to see what happens and it indeed is giving the same NoClassDefFoundError. Also I should note that the Kotlin integration works as it's not the only file (I have kotlin file for CrudRepository interface which works?...)

So my question is, how can I fix this issue? Is it possible to disable the Metadata annotation, or am I doing something wrong?

Note: I previously was able to use kotlin classes with spring when I had everything in one file, it seems like splitting code to smaller files messes with everything

This Entity class is used through CrudRepository like this (notice how it's Kotlin, porting this to Java makes no difference)

```
@Repository
interface FileRepo : CrudRepository<Example, Long> {}
```

A different manager class does this:

```
@Controller
public class FileUploadController {

    private final FileRepo fileRepo;

    @Autowired
    public FileUploadController(FileRepo fileRepo) {
        this.fileRepo = fileRepo;
    }

...

Example tosave = new Example(Idhere, nameHere);
        this.fileRepo.save(tosave);
```

This is my gradle project:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.2'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.5.20'
}

group = 'pl.szpring'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
    runtimeOnly "com.h2database:h2:1.4.200"
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```

full error log (references a class that uses the CrudRepository:

````
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'fileUploadController' defined in file [(path here)\java\main\pl\szpring\wysylanie\FileUploadController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'fileRepo' defined in pl.szpring.wysylanie.storage.FileRepo defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/reflect/full/KClasses
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1354) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at pl.szpring.wysylanie.MainKt.main(main.kt:39) ~[main/:na]```
````

Comment: It doesn't really make too much sense that `@Metadata` is the problem here. Does the  `NoClassDefFoundError` reference `Example` class or some other class? Exception message provides info which class exactly is the problem. Also, how do you build/run the application?

Comment: @broot I edited my question to include Error log and how the class is used, it does reference different class, but it's weird how only the last `Example` decides if the error pops up or not

Comment: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/reflect/full/KClasses` - so are you sure `kotlin-reflect` library is available at runtime?

Comment: Okay now it works, I didn't realise the ending of error is referencing something I'm supposed to include, I subconsciously ignored it. I have a long way in front of me, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out error log was hinting what's wrong the whole time, I was missing kotlin reflect dependency (gradle here):

```
dependencies {
   runtimeOnly 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.2.41'
   ...
}
```